# Is there an Excel formula that can conditionally sum rows based on column headers?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

[image]

I need to be able to put a formula into the last cell of a row (shown by = in the image) that totals the values in that row that don't have a cell with the text 'Done' at the top of the relevant column.

eg For the first row:

The values of 1 & 4 should be ignored, as they have 'Done' in a cell at the top of their columns, so the formula should return 7 + 10 + 13 = 30 as these values don't have 'Done' at the top.

I can't alter the actual data values (eg I can't set them to zero based on the column header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUMIF function, like this:

`=SUMIF(a1:e1; "<>Done"; a2:e2)`

First range is the range where headers are, second range is the range to sum

Comment: And if you use `=SUMIF(a$1:e$1; "<>Done"; a2:e2)` you can copy the formula down ;) (note the $)